# React Props is Not Defined

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I'm having trouble understanding why my props.updateBuilding is not working.

The following works when the prop is within the render method

```
class Buildings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchBuildings();
  }

  renderBuildings(building) {
    return (
      <div>
          <p> {building.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        {this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings)}
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.updateBuilding.bind(this, 1)}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { buildings: state.buildings.all };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchBuildings, updateBuilding}, dispatch);
}
```

But when I put `this.props.updateBuilding` to the renderBuildings method like below...

```
  renderBuildings(building) {
    return (
      <div>
          <p> {building.name}</p>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.updateBuilding.bind(this, building.id)}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

It seems that the prop `updateBuildings` cannot be read when it is inside the renderBuildings method and I'm not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you're miss-reading this error. `props` is not undefined, what is calling `props` is undefined, which is the `this` keyword. you can manually set the context of the map function by passing in a second parameter

`this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings, this)`

or bind it inline

`this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings.bind(this))`

Answer (score 32):

In my case, I forgot to add `props` as an argument to the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

Comment: This was it for me when extending a base class.

Answer (score 5):

I also had some **problems using props with my functional components** while doing the todo-tutorial. When you use functional components instead of class components, you'll have to do an import from the node-modules if you want to use props. Put this line at the top of your file:

```
import props from 'prop-types';
```

Then, when you'll want to use props in your functional component, you'll first need to pass the keyword as a parameter of this function. After that, you'll be allowed to use it like you would have in a class component but **without using the keyword "this"** :

```
function Todos(props) {
  console.log(props.todos);
  return (
    <div className="Todos">
        <h2>This is the Todos component</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shadowing the imported props variable looks like a very bad idea to me... 

Prop types are normally imported as `PropTypes` and are a completely different concept. It allows you to define required types for your component props to help with development. See prop-types docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). 

All that is required for functional components is defining `props` as an argument to your function (like you have). You definitely don't need to import `'prop-types'` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 2):

Binding inline isn't recommended anymore. Now, you can remove the constructor function altogether, and instead of declaring a method on the component, you can declare a property, and set it to an arrow function. This will bind properties to the instance.

Special shoutout to WES BOS for teaching that to me just yesterday in his React for Beginners course! :D Super pumped to actually have something to contribute to Stack Overflow!

```
renderBuildings = (buildings) => {
//this keyword is now available for use here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not recommended to bind the function directly in render or anywhere else in the component except in constructor. Because for every function binding a new function/object will be created in webpack bundle js file hence the bundle size will grow. Your component will re-render for many reasons like when you do setState, new props received, when you do this.forceUpdate() etc. So if you directly bind your function in render it will always create a new function. Instead do function binding always in constructor and call the reference wherever required. In this way it creates new function only once because constructor gets called only once per component.

Bind them in constructor and use the reference like

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderBuildings = this.renderBuildings.bind(this);
}

this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing the `this` keyword `this.props.buildings`