# Props is not defined React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using react js and I don't know why I'm getting props isn't defined.

Here is my class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const InputHeight = {
    height: '50px',
}

function clearData() {
    this.refs.input.value = "";
}



export default class TextInput extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input
                className="form-control"
                ref="input"
                name={props.name}
                type={props.inputType}
                value={props.content}
                pattern={props.pattern}
                onChange={props.controlFunc}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                style={InputHeight}
                required />
        );
    }
}


TextInput.propTypes = {
    inputType: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'number', 'email']).isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    controlFunc: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    content: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.string,
        React.PropTypes.number,
    ]).isRequired,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

> Failed to compile
>   ./src/components/Parts/SmallBits/FormItems/TextInput.js    Line 19: 
>   'props' is not defined  no-undef    Line 20:  'props' is not defined 
>   no-undef    Line 21:  'props' is not defined  no-undef    Line 22: 
>   'props' is not defined  no-undef    Line 23:  'props' is not defined 
>   no-undef    Line 24:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
this.refs.form.clearData();
```

just onClick that and it gives me

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of null

Comment: @DavinTryon updated it for you

Comment: `this.props` instead `props`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Props is Not Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622102/react-props-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In a class the way to access props is `this.props` not just `props`.

```
export default class TextInput extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input
                className="form-control"
                ref="input"
                name={this.props.name}
                type={this.props.inputType}
                value={this.props.content}
                pattern={this.props.pattern}
                onChange={this.props.controlFunc}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                style={InputHeight}
                required />
        );
    }
}
```

Here is your code revised with this change.

As for this function

```
function clearData() {
    this.refs.input.value = "";
}
```

You have 2 issues I believe. First, it is not nested within the class so the `this` keyword is not referring to this class. Second, even if it was nested, once the caller calls this function, the `this` keyword's context would now no longer be referring to your class. It is important to understand how the `this` keyword works and how to either use `bind` or `=>` functions to get around this behavior.

Comment: this fixed it but broke my clear function p.s the clear function is called from the parent where the clear button is

Comment: @andywilson I have updated my answer to address your clear function. Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you get VSCode to underline the areas in a red error underline for all lines that have `props.[propertyName]` which should be `this.props.[propertyName]` in a class component?

Answer (score -1):

import React from 'react'

export default function Component1(props){
return (
 My name is {props.name}
)
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure why you answered this when there was already an answer. But little bit of criticism, try and use the code that is used above in your answer and also put it in a code block.

Answer (score -2):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const InputHeight = {
    height: '50px',
}

function clearData() {
    this.refs.input.value = "";
}



export default class TextInput extends Component {
    render(props) {
        return (
            <input
                className="form-control"
                ref="input"
                name={props.name}
                type={props.inputType}
                value={props.content}
                pattern={props.pattern}
                onChange={props.controlFunc}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                style={InputHeight}
                required />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.